# Blender 2.8 How to hide vertices overlaying half of object in rendered view? See pic

Tags: rendering, mesh, vertices

My viewport is split. On the right side of the split my object is in rendered view (see image) but half of my rendered object shows the vertices of my object instead of the fully rendered mesh. How do I disable this setting? Blender 2.8[image]

Comment: Put your cursor/Mouse where the edit function is, then hold middle Mouse button and drag right. Then you Will find something that looks like 2 circles Press that.

Comment: @Yohello, it worked! Thanks so much!